# Durable, UV-resistant labeling for electronics enclosure

Tags: enclosure, panel

I'm not sure if this is the right forum for this question. I'm asking here in hopes that someone has dealt with this.  If this is the wrong forum, please do not vote me down. If necessary, I'll simply withdraw the question.

I need to apply labels that indicate switch functions to the exterior of an electronics enclosure that will be used outdoors.  The enclosure is made of polycarbonate and fiberglass. The labels must be permanent, waterproof, UV-, chemical and abrasion-resistant.

I've tried applying water decals and coating with epoxy and UV-resistant clear top coat, but the results are inconsistent.

Any recommendations?  I'm not looking for a specific product (as I think this would be against forum policy), rather for general guidelines.  Do you use commercially available label material or some other solution?

Comment: Have you investigated etching? Or a stainless steel tag?

Comment: PU , PE and SS ( $$$ ) tags are UV resistant.  Some are laser (fused-carbon) printable.

Comment: There Is No Such Thing as a UV Resistant Epoxy, but I find that UV film over Polycarbonate works best and lasts >> 10 yrs and you can drive a truck over the panels 2' x 12' panels ~ >$50  "Lexan"  http://www.totalplastics.com/products/578

Comment: Are you doing one-offs or a product?  If a product, do a web search on the phrase "labels for electronics".  Any remotely high-tech city will have at least one label company, and in the Age of the Internet there will be plenty that can do the deal over the wire.  If you're doing one-offs, add "prototype" to the above web search.

Comment: glue on "nametags": etched plastic labels you see on doors, military nametags, desk placards, traffic signals, etc. It won't fade and can be read even when grimy, thanks to the 3D-edness.